# Converte ImmutableMultiDict with duplicate keys to list of lists or dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

So, basically I'm trying to convert an ImmutableMultiDict object to a list of lists or dictionary, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how. The thing is I have two values for the same key, so when I try the conversion, I can only get 1 value:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'boom'), ('extension', 'pdf'), ('extension', 'doc')])
```

When I try dict(object)

```
{'name': 'boom', 'extension': 'pdf'}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you want the expected output to be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ImmutableMultiDict` object has a `lists` method.  You can use that to convert it to a dictionary with unified keys that have lists for the values.

```py
from werkzeug import ImmutableMultiDict

d = ImmutableMultiDict([('name', 'boom'), ('extension', 'pdf'), ('extension', 'doc')])
dict(d.lists())
# returns:
{'name': ['boom'], 'extension': ['pdf', 'doc']}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!